# Expected value for power of random variable divided by sum of powers

Tags: probability, random-variables, normal-distribution

Is there any hope to obtain an analytical expression for the following expectation value?

$$
\mathbb{E}\left\{ \frac{X^p}{\sum_{s\in \mathcal{S}} a_s X^s } \right\}
$$

$p \in \mathbb{N}_+$ and $\mathcal{S} \subset \mathbb{N}_+$ is a set possibly containing $p$. $X$ is a random variable. Ideally Gaussian distribution (or even better Rayleigh) but if it makes calculations easier a different distribution may be possible.

Comment: If $X>0$ and $a_s>0$ for all $s$ (to avoid issues like division by zero errors) then Jensen's inequality says $E\left[\frac{1}{\sum_s a_s X^{s-p}}\right] \geq \frac{1}{\sum_s a_s E[X^{s-p}]}$.

Comment: You might also consider a partial fraction decomposition of your ratio.  For example, then you might concentrate on solving integrals like $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{f_X(x)}{(x-c)}dx$, and $c$ cannot be a positive real root.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition